# Pressing any button would just return me Error: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I am new to using eel. Trying to create the front end for a app whose backend i already developed with python. However pressing any button would return me Error: 405 Method Not Allowed

I am trying to bring up a file dialogue when a certian button is pressed. However, pressing the button does open up window for a new dialogue but then once i select a location the page just changes to Error: 405 Method Not Allowed. I also tried other stuff but everytime after the task is completed the app would return the same error.

Python

```
import eel
import easygui

eel.init('FrontEnd')
eel.start('ui.html', size=(1000,700))

def get_director(test):
    print("Hello")
    print(test)

@eel.expose    
def get_directory():
    directory = easygui.fileopenbox()
    print(directory)
```

javascript

```
function getDataDirectory() {
    eel.get_directory();
}
```

I also have /eel.js added in the head of the html. I dont know if I am doing anything wrong. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If the HTML is required let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place eel.start() at the end of the code..

Python

```
import eel
import easygui

eel.init('FrontEnd')


def get_director(test):
    print("Hello")
    print(test)

@eel.expose    
def get_directory():
    directory = easygui.fileopenbox()
    print(directory)

eel.start('ui.html', size=(1000,700))
```

Hope that will solve the problem